# What material is the LEGO laptop made of?

Tags: piece-information, plastics

What material is the LEGO [laptop piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=62698&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Computer%20Laptop&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil%5D#T=C) made of? It does not feel like their normal rubber and it certainty doesn't feel like ABS.

[image]

Comment: Probably the same as other flexible parts; i believe polyethylene.

Answer (score 1):

It could be polyethylene or ABS. My guess is polyethylene because it is more flexible.

Comment: "It could be" and "my guess" aren't very strong arguments. Do you happen to have some data or source of the information to back up your answer?

Comment: @Alex Yes, I do. On my LDD app, it says made out of polyethylene. Also, polyethylene is more flexible than ABS. polyethylene would be used to make the "hinge" on the laptop, to make it close.

Comment: I wasn't aware thet LDD has such information. Your answer would greatly benefit from having such information posted in form of screenshot.

Comment: @Alex Some pieces do, some pieces don't. For example, different wall elements could be made of ABS or a variety of different plastics.